# add class to multiple titles using the title text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2010

Using the HTML Below:

```
<tr class="more-options">
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Required Hidden 1</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Required_x0020_Hidden_x0020_1" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Required_x0020_Hidden_x0020_1')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="Required_x0020_Hidden_x0020_1" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="more-options">
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Required Hidden 2</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
```

I am trying to add the class ".more-required" to the  Tags. But I want to be able to enter the title text into an array and have a javascript/jquery function add the class to the titles using the title text.

This is the Javascript I have:

```
var Req = ['Required Hidden 1','Required Hidden 2'];

for (i= 1; i <= Req.length; i++){
var page = $(".ms-standardheader nobr:contains(" +Req[i]+ ")");
page.parent().addClass('more-required');
};
```

This is just not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before you do anything, you may want to change `i = 1` to `var i = 1`.  The former will declare a `global variable`, and the latter will be a `scoped variable` specific to the `for loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
var Req = ['Required Hidden 1','Required Hidden 2'];

$('.ms-standardheader nobr').each(function(){
    for(var i = 0;i < Req.length;i++){
        if($(this).text().indexOf(Req[i]) != -1){
            $(this).addClass('more-required');
        }
    }
});
```

You would want to explicitly iterate through each nobr tag, check each array value against it's contents, and if the value is found, add the desired class.

http://jsfiddle.net/sy1L0f05/